# Serve Python app using WSGI behind reverse proxy

Tags: python-3.x, flask, uwsgi, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am developing simple web app using Python and Flask. It has to be served behind reverse proxy. My URLs before proxy have `/custom_prefix` which is removed by Nginx, so app is not directly aware of that. To fix issues related to that I use ProxyFix from `werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix`:

```
app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app, x_proto=1, x_port=1, x_for=1, x_host=1, x_prefix=1)
```

Of course I had to add some specific prefixes like to Nginx config:

```
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Prefix /custom_prefix;
```

ProxiFix uses them to fix url related issues and thanks to that methods like url_for generate proper URLs.

However, I have to serve my application using socket file and WSGI, so now I serve using uwsgi server. I have changed Nginx config because as far as I know there are no http headers in WGSI, so they have to be recreated with proper params like:

```
    uwsgi_param HTTP_X-Forwarded-Prefix /custom_prefix;
```

After these changes ProxyFix is no longer fixing prefix issue and url_for returns URLs without `/custom_prefix`. Headers seem to be recreated properly, because `request.headers` contains `X-Forwarded-Prefix`. Still ProxyFix does not do the job.